# 'javascript origins' missing in yammer App registration page

Tags: yammer

I do not find "JavaScript Origins field" in my app registration page.
Do i have enable any feature for activating this or is it a bug?
[image: This is helpful image]

Comment: Kindly add the code what you have tried

Comment: My question was, when i tried to register/create an app in https://www.yammer.com/client_applications,
The pop-up doesn't show "javascript origins" field, so if i want to make a call from my site thru javascript i cannot as it will be cross-domain.

Comment: Btn here is my code
<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="xyz" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
<span id="yammer-login"></span>
<script>
window.onload = function(){debugger;
  yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) {
    if (resp.authResponse) {
      document.getElementById('yammer-login').innerHTML = 'Welcome to Yammer!';
    }
  });
}
</script>

Comment: this is the error i got, which is expected
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.yammer.com/platform/login_status.json?client_id=xyz. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://abcd.sharepoint.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
After creating the app, you have to into basic info settings and you can add your origins in this page.